# Get color percentage OpenCv

Tags: image, delphi, opencv

How can i get the percentage of colors in a pIplImage (im using Delphi), like percentage of the Red(clRed), Green(clGreen), Blue(clBlue) in an image.

I wanted to simulate this `img.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0]` with OpenCv but didn't how to go through the image pixel by pixel but didn't know how.

exemple:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var i, j, r, b, g, tot : integer;
begin
  r := 0; b := 0; g := 0;
  for i := 0 to Image1.Width - 1 do
    for j := 0 to image1.Height - 1 do
      if image1.Canvas.Pixels[i,j] = clRed then
        inc(r)
      else if image1.Canvas.Pixels[i,j] = clBlue then
        inc(b)
      else if image1.Canvas.Pixels[i,j] = clGreen then
        inc(g);
    tot := Image1.Width * Image1.Height;
    showmessage('Red %:' + IntToStr(r div tot)+#13#10+
                'Green %:'+IntToStr(g div tot)+#13#10+
                'Blue %:'+IntToStr(b div tot));
end;
```

In my search i found out that i had to convert the `pIplImage` to a Mat (using the `cvMat()`), the split it into arrays with cvGet2D to get i guess 4 array, RGB and Gray. But didnt knew whats the next step...

```
var
    mat : TCvMat;
    res : TCvScalar;
begin
    object_filename := 'd:\1.bmp';
    image := cvLoadImage(pcvchar(@object_filename[1]), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    mat := cvMat(image.width, image.height, 0, image);
   for i := 0 to mat.rows - 1 do
     for j := 0 to mat.cols - 1 do
     begin
         res := cvGet2D(@mat, i, j);
         writeln('red: ', res.val[0]:2:2);
         writeln('green: ', res.val[1]:2:2);
         writeln('Blue: ', res.val[2]:2:2);
         writeln('Gray: ', res.val[3]:2:2);
         writeln;
    end;

    readln;
 end.
```

But that returns only val[0] with actual values, the rest are all zeros.

Finally what is the fastest way to calculate the percentage of a color using pIplImage with OpenCV. Less time, mem, cpu...

Comment: Unclear request: I know what I *think* you mean, but "How can i get the percentage of colors in a pIplImage (im using Delphi), like percentage of the Red(clRed), Green(clGreen), Blue(clBlue) in an image." can be taken a number of ways algorithmically.  You might clarify as to what part is giving you trouble *specifically*.

Comment: @Glenn1234: Good luck. I spent a long time (more than an hour) prying this much content out, and gave up when pulling teeth became too frustrating. (See the revision history of this question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
var
  img     : pIplImage;
  channels: array [0 .. 2] of pIplImage;
  BGRSum  : Array [0 .. 2] of TCvScalar;
  i, total: Integer;

begin
  try
    img := cvLoadImage(filename, 1);

    for i := 0 to 2 do
      channels[i] := cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);

    cvSplit(img, channels[0], channels[1], channels[2], 0);

    for i := 0 to 2 do
      BGRSum[i] := cvSum(channels[i]);

    total := img^.width * img^.height * 255;

    WriteLn('Color percentage of RGB(ex red 50%, green 25% and blue %25) in an image is');

    writeln('red:   ', BGRSum[2].val[0] / total * 100:2:2);
    writeln('green: ', BGRSum[1].val[0] / total * 100:2:2);
    writeln('blue:  ', BGRSum[0].val[0] / total * 100:2:2);

    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      writeln(
        E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Thanks to `Laex`